# How to cache Parquet files with too many columns in memory with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark and am having a lot of trouble to cache in memory a DataFrame loaded from a 600MB Parquet file that has both too many rows (~73K) and columns (~23K).

Here's my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .appName('Parquet Load Tests') \
            .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.parquet('./cell_level_table_aloha.parquet/')
df.createOrReplaceTempView('my_table')

spark.catalog.cacheTable('my_table')
spark.table('my_table').count()
```

After running for a while, it raises an error with a **HUGE** stack trace. If you wanna check it out, I pasted it on the end of this post.

It appears to me that the problem is related to Java's Heap Space, because `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` shows up three times in the error stack trace. The thing is, I've already configured both driver and executor memory to have 16GB each. For doing so, I added these two lines on `conf/spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.driver.memory 16g
spark.executor.memory 16g
```

I'm running this code in a Python script (with `$ python my_spark_script.py`) on a Docker container with Ubuntu 16.04 in a machine with a Intel Core i5-3470S (2.90GHz), 32GB of RAM memory and disk-only storage.

My Spark installation is the pre-compiled `spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7`. After downloading it, I exported the following environment variables to my `.bashrc` file as follows:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/path/to/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
```

The PySpark I'm using was installed via `$ pip install pyspark`. Oh, and the Python version I'm using is `2.7.12`.

It's important to note that although I'm struggling a lot to cache that DataFrame, I successfully cached a much bigger one row-wise: ~50 million rows and 34 columns. I loaded it from a 16GB+ CSV file. Due to this experiment, I'm think that maybe Spark struggles to deal with lots of columns, but deals ok with many rows. But that's just a beginner naive guess.

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem?

As mentioned above, here's the full error stack trace:

```
Setting default log level to "WARN". To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel). 18/01/30 16:19:13 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 18/01/30 16:20:41 WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf. [Stage 1:>                                                          (0
+ 4) / 6]18/01/30 16:20:47 WARN CodeGenerator: Error calculating stats of compiled class. java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
        at org.codehaus.janino.util.ClassFile.loadAttribute(ClassFile.java:1509)
        at org.codehaus.janino.util.ClassFile.loadAttributes(ClassFile.java:644)
        at org.codehaus.janino.util.ClassFile.loadFields(ClassFile.java:623)
        at org.codehaus.janino.util.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:280)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anonfun$recordCompilationStats$1.apply(CodeGenerator.scala:1036)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anonfun$recordCompilationStats$1.apply(CodeGenerator.scala:1033)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.recordCompilationStats(CodeGenerator.scala:1033)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:1001)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1067)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1064)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.compile(CodeGenerator.scala:946)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$.create(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:412)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$.create(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$.create(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:930)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.create(Projection.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.create(Projection.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection$.create(Projection.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anonfun$21.apply(DataSourceScanExec.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anonfun$21.apply(DataSourceScanExec.scala:322)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:815)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:815)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 4) / 6]18/01/30 16:24:08 WARN BlockManager: Putting block rdd_5_0 failed due to an exception 18/01/30 16:24:08 WARN BlockManager: Block rdd_5_0 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory 18/01/30 16:24:08 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.BasicColumnBuilder.initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$NullableColumnBuilder$$super$initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NullableColumnBuilder$class.initialize(NullableColumnBuilder.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$compression$CompressibleColumnBuilder$$super$initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.initialize(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.ColumnBuilder$.apply(ColumnBuilder.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:94)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) 18/01/30 16:24:08 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.BasicColumnBuilder.initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$NullableColumnBuilder$$super$initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NullableColumnBuilder$class.initialize(NullableColumnBuilder.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$compression$CompressibleColumnBuilder$$super$initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.initialize(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.ColumnBuilder$.apply(ColumnBuilder.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:94)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287) [Stage 1:>                                                          (0 + 5) / 6]18/01/30 16:24:10 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.BasicColumnBuilder.initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$NullableColumnBuilder$$super$initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NullableColumnBuilder$class.initialize(NullableColumnBuilder.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$columnar$compression$CompressibleColumnBuilder$$super$initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.initialize(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.initialize(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.ColumnBuilder$.apply(ColumnBuilder.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$2.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:94)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:92)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1038)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:969)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:760)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "caching_df_problem.py", line 12, in <module>
    spark.table('my_table').count()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 427, in count 18/01/30 16:24:10 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
    return int(self._jdf.count())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value) py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.count. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 1 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:820)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:818)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:818)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1750)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1928)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1317)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1927)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1948)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2435)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2434)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2434)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: If your machine has only 32GB of RAM, then it is likely that the 16g executor is not getting launched due to a lack of resources. Can you try reducing the driver and executor memories to 8g or 4g? If you're still facing issues, a good starting point would be to check the Spark UI and figure out how much the application has progressed.

Comment: Our machine is doing a time consuming CPU-bounded experiment at the moment, but as soon as it finishes, I'll try that. But I'm not sure if that's the issue, because as I said, I'm facing this when trying to cache a 73K rows by 23K columns DataFrame loaded from a 600MB Parquet file. When I do the same with a much bigger one in terms of both size and number of rows (50 million rows, 34 columns, 16GB), I don't face any problem. Do you think that the problem is the number of columns?